# Matplotlib plots graph in a very strange way

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

Trying to plot UV-index over the course of the day. The data comes from an api, which after some treatment gives me the data in a nice list. The plot however is absolutely disgusting.  [Link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt75K.png). Y-axis values are repeated and thrown around, so there are multiple 0s, positive numbers on both sides of the multiple 0s, and a nightmare to interpret. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
import requests
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Get weather information
response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=55.583328&lon=13.0&lang=se&exclude=minutely,daily,alerts&units=metric&appid=0f0212703cfecb4699dfc2c7edde950a")

# Save weather information to file
with open("weather.csv", 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)

# Opens the file and gets all the values of "uv-index"
with open("Weather.csv", 'r') as text:
    pattern = 'uvi":(.*?),'
    Line = text.read()
    substring = np.array(re.findall(pattern, Line))

# Creates an x-axis as a list with the same size as y-axis
# If they're not the same size, error is given:
# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (12,) and (49,)
x_axis = []
for i in range(len(substring)):
    x_axis.append(i)
x_axis = np.array(x_axis)

# Determines size and plots graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.plot(x_axis, substring)

# Creates labels
plt.title("UV-Index today")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("UV-Index")

# Saves the plot as image and shows it on screen
plt.savefig("UV-Index" + ".png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could be that your `y` values are not numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `substring` is a list of strings. Matplotlib treats strings as discrete values (so there's no difference in distance between '0' and '0.01' and '0' and '1000'; and there's no order between them, so '1000' could appear lower than '0').

Convert your `substring` to float before plotting:

```
substring = list(map(float,substring))
```

Or, since your substring is a numpy array:

```
substring = substring.astype('float')
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixes everything, and the code is pretty self-explanatory, but ask if you're confused by anything:

```py
import requests
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json

response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=55.583328&lon=13.0&lang=se&exclude=minutely,daily,alerts&units=metric&appid=0f0212703cfecb4699dfc2c7edde950a")

with open("weather.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)

# this converts the JSON as a string to JSON as a dictionary
dict1 = json.loads(response.text)

y_axis = []
for entry in dict1['hourly']:
    y_axis.append(entry['uvi'])

y_axis = np.array(y_axis)
x_axis = np.array(range(len(x_axis)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis)

plt.title("UV-Index today")
plt.xlabel("Time (Hours)")
plt.ylabel("UV-Index")

plt.savefig("UV-Index" + ".png")
plt.show()
```

[image: uv graph]

(Also, check your `weather.csv` file; it shouldn't be in a `csv` format since its json data, not table data.)

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! Always looking for better ways of coding. Never used json but this definitly seems like a better way to do it.

Comment: no problem. yeah generally when you call an API it gives you JSON data so its a good thing to learn. by the way, i just realised the axes were the wrong way round, but its fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, your Y data is not of numeric type.

Also that is definitely a new way of parsing json responses. Try this:

```
import json
s = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.json_normalize(s['hourly'])
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], unit='s')
df.plot(x="dt", y='uvi')
# Creates labels
plt.title("UV-Index today")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("UV-Index")
plt.show()
```

As requested, full example. Not sure why result is saved to a text file, but it is `json` file and not `csv` one.

```
import requests
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Get weather information
response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=55.583328&lon=13.0&lang=se&exclude=minutely,daily,alerts&units=metric&appid=0f0212703cfecb4699dfc2c7edde950a")

# Save weather information to file
with open("weather.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)

# Evaluate JSON string to JSON object
s = json.loads(response.text)

# Create DataFrame with hourly data
df = pd.json_normalize(s['hourly'])

# Convert time stamps to actual datetime values
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], unit='s')

# Determines size and plots graph
df.plot(x="dt", y='uvi', figsize=(10, 6))

# Creates labels
plt.title("UV-Index today")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("UV-Index")

# Saves the plot as image and shows it on screen
plt.savefig("UV-Index" + ".png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, haven't used requests or json before so I am pretty lost. First off: Where would I put these. I understand import and my own code, but these variable names aren't helping ;). Second, what is pd? I just get an error when i put this in my own code. It seems that you want to replace my time with the actual time of day, is that right?

Comment: @Jakzach answer updated. `pd` states for common imported name of pandas library, I missed it on first snippet. I've put comments where needed.